# Spring-boot_1.4.2 data source configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Recently I migrated to latest spring-boot version(1.4.2) . I observered few of the old properties are more supported.

Old configuration

```
spring.datasource.max-active=1
spring.datasource.validation-query=/* ping */ SELECT 1
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.initial-size=1
```

New Configuration

```
spring.datasource.dbcp.max-active=1
spring.datasource.dbcp.validation-query=/* ping */ SELECT 1
spring.datasource.dbcp.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.dbcp.initial-size=1
```

After migrating to the new configuration, My application is still consuming 10 connection which is a default configuration.

What are the additional configuration am I missing?

Comment: Which pool are you using.

Comment: I am using the default pool.Is it tomcat-jdbc?

Comment: Should be Tomcat according to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database. So I guess you should be using `spring.datasource.tomcat.*` in stead of `spring.datasource.dbcp.*`.

Comment: If you were using DBCP, if I recall correctly, `maxActive` doesn't exist, but it is `maxTotal` for DBCP.

Comment: Can you try this `spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-total=1`

Comment: The default is tomcat-jdbc. I used below configuration for it to work properly.spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=1
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=/* ping */ SELECT 1
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=1
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=3000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database), by default, Spring boot uses Tomcat JDBC. It is also included by default into **spring-boot-starter-jdbc** which is included in **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa**.

> - We prefer the Tomcat pooling DataSource for its performance and concurrency, so if that is available we always choose it.
> - Otherwise, if HikariCP is available we will use it.
> - If neither the Tomcat pooling datasource nor HikariCP are available and if Commons DBCP is available we will use it, but we don’t recommend it in production.
> - Lastly, if Commons DBCP2 is available we will use it.

This means that you should be using the `spring.datasource.tomcat.*` properties, for example:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=1
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=/* ping */ SELECT 1
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=1
```

Alternatively, if you prefer DBCP, you can do so by defining `spring.datasource.type` property and provide the fully qualified name of the connection pool implementation. In this case, you'll have to use `maxTotal` though, because `maxActive` does not exist according to [the documentation of DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html).

Remember to add the right version of DBCP to your classpath though. If you're adding 1.x, you can use the `spring.datasource.dbcp.*` properties (like you used), however, if you're using 2.x you should use the `spring.datasource.dbcp2.*` properties:

```
# Commons DBCP 1.x
spring.datasource.dbcp.max-total=1
spring.datasource.dbcp.validation-query=/* ping */ SELECT 1
spring.datasource.dbcp.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.dbcp.initial-size=1
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource # To override the default classpath lookup behaviour

# Commons DBCP 2.x
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-total=1
spring.datasource.dbcp2.validation-query=/* ping */ SELECT 1
spring.datasource.dbcp2.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.initial-size=1
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource # To override the default classpath lookup behaviour
```

Comment: The tomcat-jdbc configuration should be used if no external datasource is specified.

Comment: That's the default yes, like I quoted from the docs. It first looks for the Tomcat DataSource, and that's guaranteed to be on the classpath if you don't make any changes because it's within spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. You can change that by either removing tomcat-jdbc from your classpath, or by overriding its behaviour by using `spring.datasource.type`